# New to canning, first attempt Peach Jam

Tags: canning

First time canning my ball wide mouth jar may have gone into the water bath with the lid depressed. Must it go in with the lid in a popped up position? Now cooled, it makes a thud sound when tapped with the side of a spoon, but the lid is stuck to the jar. Any opinions on if this is properly sealed?

Comment: It sounds like you now have a serendipitous opportunity to crack into some jam!

Answer (score 9):

It should come out of the bath with the button up and as it cools, the button will pull in with a satisfying pop.

If that doesn't happen the jar might be sealed, but there just isn't a good way to know short of forcing the lid.

If the lid is stuck firmly, without jam having leaked out onto the seal, I would be confident in the seal.

If you really want peace of mind, you can clean the rim, replace the lid with a new one, and process the jar again.

Comment: Thank you. The jar is clean and lid stuck very well. I will use this jar now and gift the others.